# How do I fix "roman.sty not found" using LaTeX?

Tags: errors, moderncv

I've been using Texmaker on Ubuntu 12.04 for a while now. I've editing several documents and especially resumes. However, I've recently been experiencing several problems with LaTex and Texmaker, starting from the upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10.

Every time I try to run the file, I have the same error message :

```
! LaTeX Error: File `roman.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.3 \moderncvtheme[grey,roman]{classic}
^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
3985 strings out of 493485
55137 string characters out of 3143526
154265 words of memory out of 3000000
7282 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
42i,0n,53p,787b,152s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This problem really just started when I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10.
During the installation process, I've been notified about "some packages" removal but I don't know which ones.
I've tried to remove all the `.tex` files and packages I have and performed a new installation. The problem is still the same.

Here is a relevant part of my LaTeX document for where it errors out on:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey,roman]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{10cm}}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
```

I've also asked this question on [Tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91463/how-do-i-fix-roman-sty-not-found-using-latex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're using a non-existent option `roman` to the `classic` theme of `moderncv` here:

```
\moderncvtheme[grey,roman]{classic}
```

Unfortunately, the [homepage of `moderncv` at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) does not provide any real documentation. The only piece available about it is in the [example template file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex). It is not mentioned as a valid option in there.

In Ubuntu 12.04 there was also [no `roman.sty` file available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=roman.sty), so that makes me believe you might have had a local `roman.sty` file in the local directory some earlier time. While 12.10 upgraded TeXLive from the 2009 version to 2012, I really believe this is not the root cause for your issue.

I also believe you should ask this on [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for the specific use of this LaTeX package.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks a lot for the help.
Since the same code was working properly before I upgraded (didn't do any changes meanwhile; that's actually what I wanted to do when I had this trouble) to 12.10, I can't really explain what went wrong.
I'll check on Tex.se

Thanks again for everything :-)

Comment: @Marius, did you find a solution? If so, could you post it here for people like me who are encountering the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisR, no not really. I just followed the instructions given by gertvdijk after reinstalling TexMaker and my LaTex packages (not that I needed to but just to be sure).
I don't have that problem anymore but I can't really tell you how it got solved!
Sorry I can't be more helpful :-(

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem.  My cv compiled fine on Ubuntu 12.04 and failed to compile on Ubuntu 14.04.   I was loath to mess around with my Tex installation.  Looking at the sample file provided at `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/moderncv/examples/template.tex.gz` gave me a hint. I changed my cv file slightly and I could compile. Here is the diff:

```
diff -r1.3 noricv.tex
9a10,11
> % new template comes from /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/moderncv/examples/template.tex.gz
> 
14c16,18
< \moderncvtheme[green,roman]{classic}                % idem
---
> %\moderncvtheme[green,roman]{classic}                % idem
> \moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldst
> \moderncvcolor{green}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red
```

So just replace  `\moderncvtheme`  with `\moderncvstyle` and `\moderncvcolor`.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to find and share a very simple workaround. I downloaded all the `.sty` files and `moderncv.cls` file from the following link:

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/

And kept all those files in the directory where my `cv.tex` file is kept.

Amazingly, compiling with `pdflatex` this time produced my `cv.pdf` with NO ERRORS :)

I hope it will work for others as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)